# Python: Write two columns in csv for many lines

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have two parameters like `filename` and `time` and I want to write them in a column in a `csv` file. These two parameters are in a `for-loop` so their value is changed in each iteration.

My current python code is the one below but the resulting csv is not what I want:

```
import csv
import os
with open("txt/scalable_decoding_time.csv", "wb") as csv_file:   
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    filename = ["one","two", "three"]
    time = ["1","2", "3"]
    zipped_lists = zip(filename,time)
    for row in zipped_lists:
        print row
        writer.writerow(row)
```

My `csv` file must be like below. The `,` must be the delimeter. So I must get two columns.

```
one,   1
two,   2
three, 3
```

My `csv` file now reads as the following picture. The data are stored in one column.

Do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: And how does it look ? What is the actual problem ?

Comment: FYI, if you want fancy aligned columns , you will have to do it by hand.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added a screenshot.

Comment: hi @zinon why don't you use `zip`?

Comment: @GaurangDeshpande I suppose no. Maybe the errors occurs by the `delimeter` in `writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')`?

Comment: @AndyK I edited my question. I tried to use `zip` but the data are stored only in one column instead of two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the issue here is, you are using `writerows` instead of `writerow`

```
import csv
import os
with open("scalable_decoding_time.csv", "wb") as csv_file:   
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    level_counter = 0
    max_levels = 3
    filename = ["one","two", "three"]
    time = ["1","2", "3"]
    while level_counter < max_levels:
        writer.writerow((filename[level_counter], time[level_counter])) 
        level_counter = level_counter +1
```

This gave me the result:

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
```

Output:

[image: output screenshot in atom]
[image: output screenshot in excel]

Comment: I get the same as you but in one column in the `csv` file.

Comment: Well, csv is comma separated file right? The delimiter is `,` and it is giving you correct output. If you are checking it in excel ,then there can be a difference. I can see the result in excel 2016 as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your really good response! I found that the delimiter in my laptop is `;` so I change it in my code and I get the same output as you in excel 2016! Than you for your help!!

Comment: In excel 2013 delimiter is `;` too!

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution

Put the following code into a python script that we will call `sc-123.py`

```
filename = ["one","two", "three"]
time = ["1","2", "3"]

for a,b in zip(filename,time):
    print('{}{}{}'.format(a,',',b))
```

Once the script is ready, run it like that

```
python2 sc-123.py > scalable_decoding_time.csv
```

You will have the results formatted the way you want

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
```